# Calling getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount throws a TokenAccountNotFoundError

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter, spl-token-program

I'm working on a React app and want to send SPL tokens. I use the `@solana/spl-token`.

When I call `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` it throws a `TokenAccountNotFoundError` unless a token account already exists.

Here is my code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useConnection, useWallet } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { PublicKey, Transaction } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount, TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, createTransferInstruction } from '@solana/spl-token';

export function SendUSDC() {
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const { sendTransaction, publicKey, signTransaction } = useWallet();

  const sendTokens = async () => {
    const toPublicKey = new PublicKey('A8t59GvWSN6W3W4LKcqKNDhm9YYDEL8PSt235fyECA8J');

    // The USDC token on the Devnet
    const tokenPublicKey = new PublicKey('4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU');

    const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      publicKey,
      tokenPublicKey,
      publicKey,
      signTransaction,
      'finalized'
    );

    let toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
      connection,
      publicKey,
      tokenPublicKey,
      toPublicKey,
      signTransaction,
      'finalized'
    );

    const tx = new Transaction().add(
      createTransferInstruction(
        fromTokenAccount,
        toTokenAccount,
        fromPublicKey,
        parseInt(10 * Math.pow(10, 6)),
        [],
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
      )
    );

    const latestBlockHash = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    tx.recentBlockhash = latestBlockHash.blockhash;

    tx.feePayer = fromPublicKey;

    const hash = await sendTransaction(tx, connection);
    console.log(hash)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={!fromPublicKey} onClick={sendTokens}>
        Send 10 USDC
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without digging a lot into your question / code, I would recommend to have a look at https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount and check that you're passing the right arguments.
Let me know if that helps in any way.

Edit: After looking at your code, and the link provided, the fifth argument of the function is a boolean type (mismatch with signTransaction) that specifies whether or not the owner of the ATA is a PDA (optional argument that is false by default). You should be fine without it.

Try it like this:

const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(connection,
publicKey,
tokenPublicKey,
publicKey
);